# H264 support for webcam driver source in kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, usb, kernel-modules

I have a EVM board, which has camera connected over mipi bus,
Overall my EVM board will act as USB webcam gadget, I want my webcam board to support h264, as I was going through drivers/usb/gadget/legacy/webcam.c file in that MPEG & YUV support is there. Can anyone tell me how to add H264 support?

Kernel - 3.14

Comment: Does [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67933/webcam-device-driver-to-support-h-264) help? And you probably have to use the uvc function, not the legacy driver.